# How to calculate number of Sundays between two dates using mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to find number of Sundays between two dates using mysql. I know how to do it using PHP But i need it to be calculated using mysql.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous - you need to explain from where your dates are derived. It may be some table column or two table columns or just some values in expression.

Answer (score 8):

```
SET @START_DATE = '2014-01-22';
SET @END_DATE = '2014-06-29';
SELECT 
    ROUND((
      (unix_timestamp(@END_DATE) - unix_timestamp(@START_DATE) ) /(24*60*60)
      -7+WEEKDAY(@START_DATE)-WEEKDAY(@END_DATE)
    )/7)

 + if(WEEKDAY(@START_DATE) <= 6, 1, 0)
 + if(WEEKDAY(@END_DATE) >= 6, 1, 0) as Sundays;
```

Solution consist of 2 parts:

1. counts number of full weeks (ROUND part), obviously you'll have 7 Sundays in 7 weeks.
2. count days that are included into the not full week parts (first or last)

If you'll need to use it more than once you can wrap it into the function:

```
DROP function IF EXISTS `count_weekdays`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `count_weekdays` (startDate date, endDate date, wd int)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
RETURN ROUND((
      (unix_timestamp(endDate) - unix_timestamp(startDate) ) /(24*60*60)
      -7+WEEKDAY(startDate)-WEEKDAY(endDate)
    )/7)

 + if(WEEKDAY(startDate) <= wd, 1, 0)
 + if(WEEKDAY(endDate) >= wd, 1, 0);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you will be able to use it like this:

```
SET @START_DATE = '2018-07-03';
SET @END_DATE = '2018-07-28';
select 
  count_weekdays(@START_DATE, @END_DATE, 6) as Sundays,

  count_weekdays(@START_DATE, @END_DATE, 5) 
+ count_weekdays(@START_DATE, @END_DATE, 6) as weekends;
```

Where 6 ~ number of weekday stands for Sunday, 5 ~ Saturday.

Comment: tnx, @Strawberry, indeed, removed 'ROUND' just before, I suppose this tail appears because of big numbers.

Comment: how can i include saturday?

Comment: @EdwinBermejo, it means you have 2 dayoff/week, so you should double (x2) "ROUND" part, and update "IF"s to check if tail or head includes saturday or sunday, so it'll be: + if(WEEKDAY(@START_DATE) <= 5, 2, if(WEEKDAY(@START_DATE) <= 6, 1,0))
 + if(WEEKDAY(@END_DATE) >= 5, 2, if(WEEKDAY(@END_DATE) >= 6, 1, 0))

Comment: @EdwinBermejo, I've updated answer to make it more general, you can find your solution there

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/50695

Maybe there will be no code on this link someday so I posted it here.

the upper link will show the number of the day and with date of the sundays. if you want to find any other day change the 1 at last to 2 for monday

```
select DATE_ADD('2012-12-15', INTERVAL ROW DAY) as Date,
row+1  as DayOfMonth from (
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t1,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t2, 
(SELECT @row:=-1) t3 limit 31
) b
where 
DATE_ADD('2012-12-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY)
between '2012-12-01' and '2012-12-31'
and
DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2012-12-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY))=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work...

```
 SELECT FLOOR(
         (DATEDIFF(
            '@enddate'
           ,'@startdate' + INTERVAL 
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX('654321',WEEKDAY('@startdate'),1)) 
              DAY) + 1)/7) + 1 x;
```

Comment: Please check your solution for the values from '2014-06-07' to '2014-07-05'

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.StartDate, a.EndDate,
    (DAY(EndDate - StartDate) / 7)   
    +  iif(DAY(EndDate - StartDate)%7 + DATEPART(DW, StartDate) > 8 , 1, 0)
    Sundays FROM
    (SELECT GETDATE() StartDate, DATEADD(DAY, 11, GETDATE()) EndDate) a
```

This is useful for multiple start and end dates in a table. 
no need of variables and loops!

How it works: determines the number of full weeks between start and end date,

determines the days less than a week and add with the start day index(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) if that value Greater than count 8(means which is Sunday !)

For Sunday week day index is 1, day 8 is nothing but index 1.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select count(DAYNAME(your_date_field)='Sunday') as sunday from tbl_name where your_date_field between 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

Comment: This assumes the OP has a table of all dates. This is an unreasonable assumption.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
WHERE column BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'
AND WEEKDAY(date) = 6;
```

Comment: This assumes the OP has a table of all dates. This is an unreasonable assumption.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this, mysql have a function dayofweek, you can easily calculate starting week day and after that divide the number of days with 7:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
WHERE date_column_of_table_name BETWEEN '2013-01-11' AND '2013-03-01'
AND WEEKDAY(date_column_of_table_name) = 6
```