# Datediff but excluding certain days of week

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am currently working on a query that calculates the datediff in days between a start_date and getdate(). However, I always need to exclude Saturdays, Sundays and Mondays.

Does someone have an idea on how I can execute this? I would need the sla column to exclude days where our agents don’t touch tickets (Saturday, Sunday and Monday).

My current code is:

```
SELECT
    ticket_id,
    status,
    create_date,
    CASE
        WHEN status = ‘Open’
            THEN datediff(‘days’, create_date, getdate())
    END AS sla
FROM tickets
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output as text  ?

Answer (score 0):

See several solutions at [How to calculate number of Sundays between two dates using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165407/how-to-calculate-number-of-sundays-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

You might want to have a User-defined function to calculate the number of days between the two dates, subtract the number of Saturdays, subtract the number of Sundays, subtract the number of Mondays, then use

```
    SELECT
    ticket_id,
    status,
    create_date,
    CASE
        WHEN status = ‘Open’
            THEN YourFunction(create_date, getdate())
    END AS sla
FROM tickets
```

Alternatively you could set up a dimension table that stores each possible create_date with a second column that has these calculations pre-done. Then do an inner join between `tickets` and the dim-table